# oracle materialized view fast refresh

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I want to find out if materialized views are a useful instrument for our reporting system. First I need to understand its functionality. therefore i've made a simple example. after an insert all data look like this

[image]

after a while we have some changes in data:

[image]

now I would like to refresh the view when run = 0 is complitly updated on table. is that possible? and what would happen when run = 1 is finished before run = 0 is calculated/refreshed? Finally I should be able to handle approximatly 60'000 file-ids with a total of around 25 million doc-ids. Current oracle version is 11. who can help me?

Comment: Please, clarify your question and add more details: describe what should be done after which event and who controls this event? We do not know the semantics you have (`run`, `file_id` etc). Did you check the concepts of the [materialized view](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF01302)?

Comment: oracle 11 is really obsolete and out of support. You should start thinking also in upgrading.

Comment: please, don't add images or pictures. Provide text of your table and MV and clear details of what you try to accomplish

Comment: Oracle 11 is not my decision. Would it be possible to contact you Roberto Hernndez by e-mail? I think it would be easier to explain my situation.